# authentication with firebase authorization with custom service

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I need to use the authentication service from firebase. but use my existing authorization service.

Can i use user token, sessions info from  `firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {})`

what is the best way/ways to manage these kind of use cases.
Should i also store my user details cookies, token etc?

Answer (score 0):

You can [implement a custom provider](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/custom-auth) for Firebase Authentication. In this process:

1. You sign the user in to your service with their credentials as usual.
2. You then [mint a token](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens) based on the user's profile.
3. The user then uses that token to sign in to Firebase.

The entire process is quite well documented on the links I included above.